# Create New Dataframe Conditionally Based On Another Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as such:

```
dfA=pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
dfB=pd.DataFrame([[True,False,False],[False,True,False]])
```

How do i create a new dataframe where based on the same index,

```
2 ** (dfA+1) only if dfB is true 
2 ** (dfA) only if dfB is false.
```

What I like to achieve is a dataframe as such:

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame([[4,4,8],[16,64,64]])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DataFrame.mask:

```
(2 ** dfA).mask(dfB, 2 ** (dfA+1))
Out: 
    0   1   2
0   4   4   8
1  16  64  64
```

This will check dfB, if True, take the values from the original DataFrame (`(2 ** dfA)`) and if false, take the values from the other (`2 ** (dfA+1)`).

This is similar to numpy's where function:

```
np.where(dfB, 2 ** (dfA+1), 2 ** (dfA))
Out: 
array([[ 4,  4,  8],
       [16, 64, 64]])
```

However, it loses the index and columns so you may need to wrap the result in a DataFrame constructor:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(dfB, 2 ** (dfA+1), 2 ** (dfA)), dfA.index, dfA.columns)
Out: 
    0   1   2
0   4   4   8
1  16  64  64
```